# Git doesn't work on MacOS Catalina: "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing"

Tags: bash, git, macos, zsh, macos-catalina

After upgrading to MacOS X 10.15 Catalina, I cannot run any git commands in my shell:

> The default interactive shell is now zsh.
>
> To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
>
> For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
>
> ~ | git
>
> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I thought there's a problem with my shell, so I followed the instructions to change the default Mac OS shell back to bash, using the GUI and also using the command line:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

I also restarted the computer. However, I still see the same message, even though `echo "$SHELL"` outputs `/bin/bash`.

Comment: What has the shell got to do with anything?  This looks like an issue with the Xcode command line tools.

Comment: Answered at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a/254381#254381

Answer (score 463, accepted):

You'll need to reinstall the command line tools:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Comment: It worked! Also add `export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1` to your `~/.bash_profile` file to get rid of the annoying message.

Comment: Learn this command by heart. It is almost always the answer to development issues after upgrading macOS.

Comment: `xcode-select --reset` was the solution for my device.

Comment: sudo xcode-select --reset worked. However it additionally required to agree to terms and conditions. The command was:

 sudo xcodebuild -license

Comment: It may be possible to dodge the license agreement by running `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` instead of the provided command.

Comment: You can also run `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` to accept it without a prompt.

Comment: if it writes `xcode-select command not found` or something like that, just reboot after the OS upgrade and try run the `xcode-select --install` again.

Comment: `sudo xcode-select --reset` worked for me without any hassle.

Comment: `sudo xcode-select --reset` worked for me.

Comment: The install command said "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server". Any idea how to get pass this?

Comment: @Guna I manually downloaded and installed the CMD line tools from: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools I used the Xcode 12 version.

Comment: sudo xcode-select --reset works for me.

Comment: PYCHARM: It did not work for me. Terminal spewed out this message to me: "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates". I then went to: (Pycharm) Preferences -> Version Control -> Git. And there I set Path to Git executable to /usr/bin/git     ----- *NOTE: I have just today updated my macOS M1 2020 to VENTURA OSX 13.0*